# How should be a return of validate function to break or continue another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I created a function to validate date of hotel checkIn and checkOut, example:

```
function reverseDate(date) {
  try {
    const regex = '^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})';
    const dateFormated = date.match(regex);
    return `${dateFormated[2]}/${dateFormated[1]}/${dateFormated[3]}`;
  } catch (error) {
    return [{ mensagem: 'Date is not valid!' }];
  }
}

function isValidDate(d) {
  return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d);
}

function validacao(checkin, checkout) {
  // Check data is null, undefined or empty
  if (!checkin || !checkout) {
    return [{ mensagem: 'Fill CheckIn and / or Checkout.' }];
  }

  // Permit only string entry date
  if (typeof (checkin) === 'string' && typeof (checkout) === 'string') {
    let checkIn = new Date(reverseDate(checkin));
    let checkOut = new Date(reverseDate(checkout));
    // Date is not valid
    if (!isValidDate(checkIn) || !isValidDate(checkOut)) return [{ mensagem: 'Date is not valid!' }];
    // CheckIn can be equal or less than CheckOut 
    if (checkIn === checkOut) {
      return [{ mensagem: 'Checkout must be greater than CheckIn' }];
    }
    // Checkout can be less than CheckIn
    if (checkOut < checkIn) {
      return [{ mensagem: 'Checkout can be less than Checkin' }];
    }
  } else {
    return [{ messagem: 'Data type is not valid, only string.' }];
  }

}
```

OK, let's suppose this is my main function:

```
function main(checkin,checkout){
  validate(checkin,checkout);

  //Logic Continues
}
```

The flux always continue, but I need to break, when I test for example:

```
{checkin:'11022021', checkout: '' }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main` you have to examine the return value of `validate`. The return value is currently discarded. Moreover, the `validate` function returns an error message when it finds a problem, but does not return anything when `checkin` and `checkout` are OK.

Here is what I would do:

1. Return something at the end of `validate`, say an empty array: `return [];`
2. Capture the return value in `main`: `const validationErrors = validate(checkin, checkout);`
3. Examine the `validationErrors` array. If its length is not zero, then you have validation errors. These errors should be displayed to the user and after that you can leave `main` by simply `return`-ing from it.

Comment: Great @kol, but if you allow me, at one of my rules, `checkin === checkout` does not work, can help me

Comment: These are Dates, so you have to compare their value: `if (checkin.valueOf() === checkout.valueOf()) {`

Comment: "The valueOf() method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf